# Get browser bookmark uri knowing only package name

Tags: android, browser, browser-history

A can get all installed web browsers by using this code:

```
ArrayList<String> allLaunchers = new ArrayList<String>();

Intent allApps = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
List<ResolveInfo> allAppList = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(allApps, 0);
for(int i =0;i<allAppList.size();i++) allLaunchers.add(allAppList.get(i).activityInfo.packageName);

Intent myApps = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
       myApps.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.google.es"));
List<ResolveInfo> myAppList = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(myApps, 0);
for(int i =0;i<myAppList.size();i++){
    if(allLaunchers.contains(myAppList.get(i).activityInfo.packageName)){
        Log.e("match",myAppList.get(i).activityInfo.packageName+"");
    }
}
```

link: [Android Fetch installed and default browser in device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10512597/android-fetch-installed-and-default-browser-in-device)

Based on package name, is there a way to get BOOKMARKS URI for each browser?

When I got list of browsers, by package name (via above method), I need to get a link for it's bookmarks (browsing history) database, for example:

On Chrome, package name is `com.android.chrome` and history URI is `content://com.android.chrome.browser/bookmarks`, but this case is special one, when only `.browser` was added to real package name... in most cases it differs totally. Like in FF, where package name is `org.mozilla.firefox`, and history uri differs: `content://org.mozilla.firefox.db.browser/bookmarks` (yes, I know that It can't be read in FF), but was only an example.

**So basically the question is:** Is there a way, knowing this: `org.mozilla.firefox`, to get this: `content://org.mozilla.firefox.db.browser/bookmarks`.

Comment: Can you please explain you're problem? You are talking about a list of installed webbrowsers and then about a BOOKMARLS_URI (History). What is is that you want to get exactly?

Comment: I want to scan history in all installed browsers, if it is allowed. I know that most most browser uri is something like content://*package name*.browser/bookmark. Just wanted to know is there a more reliable way of getting this info